# Problems with Vue.js $ interpolation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.JS and not that expert with Javascript. I am watching a tutorial which is using Vue 2, asap i will switch to the v3. I have problems to replicate a simple code. Here the code:

```
var app = new Vue({ el: "#app", data: { name: "Mike" }, methods: { getFullName() { return 'Name: ${this.name}'})
```

It doesen't even work on the console. It is returning the string as is: Name: ${this.name}

Tried to assign the value of name to a local variable inside the getFullName method but still not working.

Comment: The code you're showing is a syntax error, I wouldn't expect it to work.  Any JavaScript engine trying to execute this code will report this error to you.  As for returning the string as-is, did you mean to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use back-ticks sign in `getFullName` method.

```
var app = new Vue({ el: "#app", data: { name: "Mike" }, methods: { getFullName() { return `Name: ${this.name}`})
```

Comment: Another day, another lesson. Thank you!